# list background color

Tags: css

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/3213/menub.jpg](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/3213/menub.jpg)

How to extend the background color of the Test2 to the left.

Comment: This looks like a JQuery menu. To get the effect you're after, quite a lot of re-working is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove all `margin` from the `li` and all `padding` from the `ul`:

```
ul { padding-left: 0; }
li { margin-left: 0; }
```

If that gives you layout problems, try adding more `padding-left` to the `li`.

If your bullet images are impossible to position correctly when you take away the `ul`'s `padding`, you could consider using a `background-image` in the `li` instead.

Comment: not sure but those bullets won't make it go to left or whole list along with bullets will be moved to left, so no gain i think

Comment: His problem is that the `li`'s background colour doesn't stretch to the left, because the space to the left is occupied by the `ul`s padding. Removing those values should fix it, but brings a bunch of other issues, which is why he may have to use different bullets.

Answer (score 1):

Were the html to look like this:

```
<ul>
 <li/>
 <li class="expanded">
  <ul>
   <li/>
   <li/>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'd use something like the following css:

```
ul, li {padding:0; margin:0;}
ul li { padding-left: 20px; background: transparent url('collapsed.gif') no-repeat top left;}
ul li.expanded {background-image: url('expanded.gif'); background-color: blue;}
ul li.expanded ul {padding-left: 20px;}
ul li.expanded ul li {padding-left: 20px; background-image: url('sub_bullet.gif');}
```